# Why is replaced outlet dead?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

Electrical outlets

I changed a pair of old 2 prong outlets to new ones with ground and grounded to the box that was already grounded.

It was a simple 2 wire with ground procedure.  However when I turned the breaker back on, there was no longer any power to the box.

What happened?

Comment: How did you know the box was grounded? Can you post photos of the inside of the box?

Answer (score 1):

The power, usually black, goes on the brass color screw. The other wire, usually white goes on the silver screw.  The box is only grounded if it is connected to the breaker box by continuious metal conduit or a ground wire.  The green ground wire is connected to the metal box and the green screw.  The green wire will not keep the outlet from working unless it is a ground fault plug.